# Streamlit and ContainDS ImportError: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable

Tags: python, docker, streamlit

am trying to run a simple Streamlit app, using ContainDS (https://containds.com/) on a Macbook.
The objective is to export a file and use ContainDS to easily share a dashboard with a client.

The project folder, placed on my desktop, has the following structure:

```
project_1234:
         ---- streamlit_app.py
         ---- Additional_scripts:
                               ---- ... .py
```

However, as soon as I launch Docker and ContainDS, instantiate a streamlit-single image, specify folder "project_1234" and click on create, the following error is displayed :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    refresh()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/__init__.py", line 73, in refresh
    if not Git.refresh(path=path):
...

ImportError:
Bad git executable.

The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:   
- be included in your $PATH   
- be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE   
- explicitly set via git.refresh()
```

Furthermore, even if I run a simple Streamlit intro.py script, the same error is reported;

However, if run the app through from Terminal, from project folder, everything works fine:

```
streamlit run streamlit_app.py
```

For your reference, I'm using Python 3.7.9 on my OS, based on anaconda.

How can I solve this issue and share the app with my client?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a recent version of Streamlit might have inadvertently added `git` as a dependency. Installing git resolves this issue.

Comment: How would you install and configure that? Could you please provide code guidance? Thank you

Comment: When you install git, it will set itself up. Here are the instructions for major operating systems, from your error I presume you need the Linux instructions https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-create a new container this morning - based on the same folder and without priorly starting Anaconda nor Spyder - and it is now successfully running.

I'm supposing that there may be some kind of conflict between those two (ContainDS/Docker and Anaconda/Spyder).